# Docker install: can't open database

Tags: docker

I installed the docker version of AzerothCore with the chromiecraft instructions and it seems to run buttery smooth.
That said, I don't seem to be able to access the databases with SQLyog or HeidiSQL.
How else can I access auth and world tables?
I am familiar with using these tools to open the databases with other projects.
Sorry if this seems basic to others.  It does not seem so to me.
Thanks in advance for any help!  I'd like to do things such as update realmlist table  and export characters so they can survive db updates.
:)

Comment: show some logs, or error messages for better understanding and also provide code/instructions that can help people replicate the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker, usually, different services are isolated, each one in its container, which means that your server should be on a different container than your database.

I have no idea what is chromiecraft, nor I have ever used AzerothCore, but I've checked [their guide](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/install-with-docker) and they are using docker-compose to launch an array of containers (3 in total), one for each service (auth server, world server, database).

[image]

If you followed this guide, you can see that the port for the database is exposed, and is as follows:

[image]
So, the address would be `localhost:3306` (if you're running it inside your computer, either way replace `localhost` with your IP), username: `root`, password: `password`.